# python checking for files

Tags: python, urllib2

learning python there. I want to write a script to check if my webserver has picture named  in the root 123.jpg

I have:

```
import urllib2
numeruks=100
adresiuks="http://localhost/" + str(numeruks) +".jpg"
try:
    if numeruks < 150:
    numeruks = numeruks + 1
    urllib2.urlopen(adresiuks).read()
```

reading manuals all day, can't solve it :(

Comment: So what happens when you try to run your program?

Comment: It is not a valid program, BTW. You have a try clause without a except or finally. And the indentation is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for 404 in your attempts to access the URL (and without even having to issue a `read()`):

```
import urllib2

n = 123

try:
    url = 'http://localhost/%d.jpg' % n
    urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    if e.code == 404:
        print '%d.jpg was not found' % n
    else:
        raise  # if the issue wasn't a 404, then re-raise the exception
```

Comment: Should also check 200 before throwing an exception.

Comment: Good thinking Jay, though a 200 response won't raise an HTTPError in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code standing on its own?  If so, you're missing a loop. Also, as codeape said, the indentation is wrong and you need an `except` or a `finally`.

If you want to check all of the numbers between 100 and 150, you'll need to loop over them.  Your code as it stands now only updates `numeruks` once, and never updates `adresiuks` at all.  If you want to check for an error with a `try`, you need to follow it up with an `except`, which can be as simple as `pass` (but will more likely be `continue`).

I'm a little hesitant to give you the actual code, as if you're learning, you'll probably learn it better if you figure it out yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

After you increment numeruks you should reset the adresiuks.

I.E.:

```
adresiuks="http://localhost/" + str(numeruks) + ".jpg"  
try:  
    if numeruks < 150:  
        numeruks = numeruks + 1  
        adresiuks = "http://localhost/" + str(numeruks) + ".jpg"  
        print adresiuks  
        urllib2.urlopen(adresiuks).read()
```

Double check the file is available using your web browser.

For example my web server is listening on port 8000 so I have to add the port, i.e. 
`http://localhost:8000/123.jpg`.

Here is a simple running script, because it is a .jpg it will be garbage that is printed:

```
import urllib2    
numeruks = 123    
adresiuks = "http://localhost/" + str(numeruks) + ".jpg"    
print adresiuks    
thefile = urllib2.urlopen(adresiuks).read()
print thefile
```